# Best way to write to JSON file in Node 10/Angular 7?

Tags: json, typescript, angular7

I'm not sure if this question belongs here, but this is driving me insane.
**I am running Node v10.16.0. Sorry!**

Since in Angular 7 `fs` no longer works - what is the best way to write to a JSON file?

Importing a JSON file now works nice and easy, but how do I write to it?

Edit: Adding what I tried.

`component.ts`:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
[...]
saveChanges(changes) {
    fs.writeFile('config.json', JSON.stringify(config), null);

Error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' `
```

Comment: You should show at least what you tried

Comment: Angular apps executes in the brower. Bowser apps aren't allowed to write files.

Comment: That is true, but NodeJS used to offer the `fs` module (or was it angular? anyway, it worked.) you could use `fs.writeFile()` for example.

Comment: Well, it's important to understand what environment you're running your code on, otherwise you run into exactly these types of situations.

Comment: Yes, but NodeJS is used to write server applications, not browser applications.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I am running Node v10.16. I must confess I learned all this by doing, so my understanding is lacking.

Comment: What do you need to do with the json file?

Comment: If you're running an Angular application, then you're not running Node at all. The browser executes your Angular application, not NodeJS.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `fs` from within Angular is not possible - and usually not what you want to do.

Angular is a Front-End Framework that is used to bind data to a UI. This happens in a Browser environment, not NodeJS.

What you are most likely doing is serving your Angular application using some kind of NodeJS Server (like express, or the Angular CLI).

Comment: Exactly, sorry. I am running Angular CLI.